# ¿Como juntar dos DATFRAME y que los datos de una columna sustituyan a la otra dado el ID?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo dos Dataframes
Quiero sustituir los valores del Primer Dataframe del segundo Dataframe he usado el merge y el concat pero me dejan los valores nulos.

Reemplaze el Index por el ID

```
data3.set_index('ID',inplace = True)
report_3.set_index('ID',inplace = True)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero reemplazar los datos de la columna NOMBRE_AP, NACIMIENTO y BAUTISMO sin perder los datos de data 3.

Que función pudiera utilizar?

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar [update](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) y [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) para sustituir las columnas de la siguiente forma:

```
data3.NOMBRE_APE.update(data3.index.map(report_3.NOMBRE_APE))
```

Explicación:

1. Eliges la columna que deseas actualizar y utilizas el método `update()`
2. Eliges la columna (En este caso los índices) que vas a utilizar para la relación y utilizas el método `map()`
3. Eliges la columna del segundo `dataframe` que va a reemplazar los valores del primer `dataframe` (Donde estás haciendo el `update` y `map`

Solo tienes que repetir para las columnas que necesites reemplazar

**Edición:** A continuación te muestro un ejemplo genérico donde se hace `update` a una columna con valores `NaN`

Tengo un `dataframe` (`df`) con los siguientes datos:

```
    Date        A   B
0   2005-01-01  NaN 156
1   2005-01-02  NaN 139
2   2005-01-03  NaN 133
3   2005-01-04  NaN 39
4   2005-01-05  NaN 33
```

Y un segundo `dataframe` (`df2`) con los siguientes datos

```
    A
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
```

Al hacer `update` y `map` con la siguiente línea de código

```
df.A.update(df.index.map(df2.A))
```

Al imprimir `df` obtengo esto

```
    Date        A   B
0   2005-01-01  1.0 156
1   2005-01-02  2.0 139
2   2005-01-03  3.0 133
3   2005-01-04  4.0 39
4   2005-01-05  5.0 33
```

Comment: Primero gracias por las respuesta, no había visto esa función update, lo intente pero no me actualiza la columna. Me sigue apareciendo con los NaN, otra pregunta esa función tmb sirve para actualizar aunque no sea valor nulo? Saludos

Comment: @JulioCesarCeballosRamos, buen día, agregué un ejemplo genérico, si funciona con los `NaN`